# How to get utma utmz and similiar cookies with php curl?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I noticed that my browser keeps different cookies than my curl cookie files:

```
"__utma=256586655.848991821.1337158982.1337158982.1337179787.2; __utmz=256586655.1337179787.2.2.utmcsr=login.example.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/company.php; __utmc=256586655; PHPSESSID=8sedo85uc5rfpnluh06bdb0mk4"
```

And this is my curl based cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

login.example.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   8peqektoc5j3570h08efa6o3n2
```

So, how to create utma utmz values and what is that values stand for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Google Analytics cookies.  Possibly, you're not telling curl to download third-party scripts referenced by the page.

Try wget with `--page-requisites` and `--save-cookies` and `--load-cookies`.  It will download files used by the page, such as scripts.

Unfortunately, it still might not load Analytics if it's using the typical script-driven async loader, since JavaScript has to actually execute for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Those are Google Analytics cookies.  Unless you pull & run those scripts (faking the Javascript runtime environment of a browser), you won't get them.  Fortunately, they're irrelevant to anything you actually want to do.